# "publishedAfter" parameter in Youtube Data API does not work as expected

Tags: youtube, google-api

I am making a call to the endpoint search in Youtube Data API using the following URL:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&type=video&publishedAfter=2015-01-10T00:00:00Z&access_token=access_token

However, when I put the "publishedAfter" parameter, I get a confused answer:

```
{   "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "youtube.search",
        "reason": "invalidSearchFilter",
        "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters.",
        "locationType": "parameter",
        "location": ""
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request contains an invalid combination of search filters and/or restrictions. Note that you must set the <code>type</code> parameter to <code>video</code> if you set a value for the <code>eventType</code>, <code>videoCaption</code>, <code>videoCategoryId</code>, <code>videoDefinition</code>, <code>videoDimension</code>, <code>videoDuration</code>, <code>videoEmbeddable</code>, <code>videoLicense</code>, <code>videoSyndicated</code>, or <code>videoType</code> parameters."   } }
```

I have already tested with the parameters of the error message and the call does not work. Does anyone have any idea why this occurs? I've tried different date formats in "publishedAfter", but none worked.